# All products not redirected to base URL after forced SSL

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, ssl

I forced SSL in Magento by going to Config -> Web and changing both the secure and unsecured settings to HTTPS.

The site works great so far... with the exception to one thing I found this morning.

Nearly every single URL on my site that is non-SSL before  doesn't redirect to its HTTPS version. instead it just redirects to the base URL.

Any ideas? What information do I need to present?

---

I added the following code to the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

but instead of example i put in my url.

As soon as i did that and tried to refresh my page, i got an error that my site was not redirecting properly and it broke.

Comment: have you set  secure and unsecure url to be in https..

Comment: Yes. That was the first thing I mentioned in the post. I went into the Config -> web settings and set both unsecure and secure settings to the httpS

Comment: Updated post. I tried to add in the rewrite rule and i started to get an error that my site was redirecting incorrectly.  I'm not that knowledgeable when it comes to this stuff. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The .htaccess code mentioned in the solution was not working and was creating redirection errors.  I did more research and found that this redirection works.    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]